# Access a specific member of inherited class via dynamic binding

Tags: c++

Imagine I have two classes `A` and `B`:

```
class A{
public:
    virtual void print(){
        cout << "I'm A!" << endl;
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void print() override {
        cout << "I'm B!" << endl; 
    }
    
    int specificMemberB; 
};
```

and I have a container of pointers to classes A in which I put the pointers to B:

```
B* b1 = new(B);
B* b2 = new(B);
B* b3 = new(B);
B* b4 = new(B);

std::vector<A*> vecA;

vecA.push_back(b1);
vecA.push_back(b2);
vecA.push_back(b3);
vecA.push_back(b4);
```

Now, when I access the element of the container, is there a way to get `specificMemberB` of class `B`?

```
vecA[0]->specificMemberB; // error: ‘class A’ has no member named ‘specificMemberB’
```

If it's not possible with current implementation what would you do instead to get `specificMemberB`?

I've thought about creating the member `specificMemberB` inside `A`, and create something like virtual getter function, but I think this is not I want, since `specificMemberB` is irrelevant for `A`.
Also, StackOverflow suggested me the question related to static, but I think I can't do this since there are multiple instantiations of the class `B` and each of them has a unique value of `specificMemberB`.
StackOverflow also suggested the question related to Factory Method Pattern, but after reading Wikipedia a while, I think this is not the case for me.

Wikipedia says:

> The Factory Method design pattern solves problems like: [2]
>
> - How can an object be created so that subclasses can redefine which class to instantiate?
> - How can a class defer instantiation to subclasses?

But I think my question is related to acessing the class member, not creating classes. So it's probably irrelevant (although I might be wrong)

I'm not sure if this is possible. But suspect it has to, since the elements of `vecA` have now dynamic type of `B` (and sure, static type of `A`)

Comment: You want a "downcast", which is almost always some form of XY problem. If you have a container of `A`, why do you want to access part of those `A` that may not exist (since they don't have to be `B`s)? If you're reliant on them actually being `B`s, why do you not simply have a container of `B`s? And if you're asking each one if it is a `B`, then you're violating the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: You can only get it if you write a virtual function in `A` and override it in `B`  so it returns the value (or reference)